# How can I initial an anonymous function into a variable and use it later?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

Here is my code:

```
Promise.all([
    ajaxRequest(value, 'search/twitter', 'twitter').then(
        function(res) {
            var imgStatus = res[1].length > 0 ? "successfully.png" : "noRes.png";
            $('.option_name_twitter + td').html("<img src='img/" + imgStatus + "' />")

            optionsRes['twitter'] = res[1];
            $('input.twitter').show();

        }, function(err){
            console.log(err);
            $('.option_name_twitter + td').html("<img src='img/warning.png' />")
        }
    ),
    ajaxRequest(value, 'search/instagram', 'instagram').then(
        function(res) {
            var imgStatus = res[1].length > 0 ? "successfully.png" : "noRes.png";
            $('.option_name_instagram + td').html("<img src='img/" + imgStatus + "' />")

            optionsRes['instagram'] = res[1];
            $('input.instagram').show();

        }, function(err){
            $('.option_name_instagram + td').html("<img src='img/warning.png' />")
        }
    )
]).then(() => {
    stopBlinking()
    formSubmited = false;
}).catch( (err) => {
    console.error(err);
    stopBlinking()
    formSubmited = false;
})
```

As you see I have two functions into `promise.all()` method. Sometimes I need to call only one of those function separately. Something like this:

```
$("input.twitter").on('click', function(){
    // only the first function should be called here
})

$("input.instagram").on('click', function(){
    // only the second function should be called here
})
```

These ^ will be called after when `Promise.all()` is executed once. Because both `input.twitter` and `input.instagram` are hidden at first and will be shown after `Promise.all()` call.

So I want to initial those anonymous functions (which are exist at `promise.all()`) into variables, and use them on click of `input.instagram` and `input.twitter`. How can I do that?

Comment: Make them not anonymous would be my suggestion

Comment: *into variables* `var variable = function(){...}`. *use them on click*, `$('input').on('click', function(){ if($(this).hasClass(...)) {... }else if( $(this).hasClass(...)){...} })`

Comment: Are you talking about the functions you are passing to `.then` or about the `ajaxRequest` calls?

Comment: @FelixKling `ajaxRequest`

Comment: Why cannot you call the function within event handlers using current code?

Comment: Just FYI, `ajaxRequest(...)` is a function *call*. "Anonymous function" usually refers to a function *definition* (without a name). E.g. the functions you pass to `.then` are anonymous functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put the code in two functions?

```
function searchTwitter() { // maybe specify `value` as argument
  return ajaxRequest(value, 'search/twitter', 'twitter').then(...);
}

function searchInstagram() {
  return ajaxRequest(value, 'search/instagram', 'instagram').then(...);
}

Promise.all([searchTwitter(), searchInstagram()]).then(...);
// and whenever you want:
searchTwitter().then(...);
searchInstagram().then(...);
```

You can [learn more about functions in *Eloquent JavaScript*](http://eloquentjavascript.net/03_functions.html).

Comment: *use them on click of*, this part is missing.

Comment: @Rajesh: That's the `and whenever you want:` part.

Comment: @FelixKling Why cannot OP call the function within event handler using current code?

Comment: @guest271314: How should that be possible? They didn't define any functions that can be called and I assume they don't want to copy and paste the whole thing.

Comment: @FelixKling Is `ajaxRequest` not a defined function?

Comment: @guest271314: I guess it's defined somewhere but as I said I assume they don't want to copy and paste the whole function call (including the arguments passed to `.then`) into the event handlers.

Comment: @guest271314 The problem was I didn't want to write the same code twice. And now by wrapping that code into a function, I write that code once and call it twice. Thank you Felix Kling. Upvote

Comment: @MartinAJ If the code at Answer resolves issue consider accepting the Answer

Comment: I got something, those functions you defined should be placed outside of `.ready()` to be working. Did you know that @FelixKling ?

Comment: @MartinAJ: They have to defined in the same scope or a higher scope where you want to access them. If you want to access them outside of the `ready()` callback then you have to define them outside of it.